# Does Liam Neeson give voiceover for Batman in Batman Begins?

Tags: batman-begins

There is a specific scene in Batman Begins, when Rachel Dawes is poisoned and Batman has to take her to his cave. James Gordon, suggests Batman to take his car, but Batman says "**I brought Mine**". This specific dialogue, if you hear clearly, seems to have been spoken by Liam Neeson, its unmistakable. Can anyone confirm. Here's the relevant scene, it's right at the beginning:

Comment: Is there anything that makes you doubt it could be anyone else than Christian Bale, apart from it just sounding similar to Liam Neeson? While I don't say it isn't so, the fact that there is absolutely no valid reason this could be anyone else than Bale, let alone Liam Neeson, and that his voice is quite distorted in general, making clear attribution difficult, speaks quite against there being any reasonable premise to your theory.

Comment: If you hear it, you would know its unmistakable

Comment: Adding to Napoleon, why would they pay Neeson a fee to do one line, and what would be the benefit of having a single line spoken by a different actor?  It defies logic.

Comment: @JohnnyBones: Maybe Bale forgot to dub for that line, and wasn't available when the error was discovered, so Liam filled it for him..

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: You are correct in saying that Batman's voice is distorted from Bruce Wayne, but its consistent. The dialogue I am referring to is in a different voice, and to me it sounded like Liam's. You see if it was Batman's voice, I would not be pointing to a specific dialogue, rather the whole voice throughout the movie.

Comment: Related: http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/10452/49.

Comment: Sounds much more like Bale than Neeson to me

Answer (score 3):

<sup>I wasn't sure if this holds as an actual answer, but I'll write it anyway. I'd rather say the burden of proof lies on the question's theory here, but in lack of a more "official" answer for now, here's my reasoning:</sup>

**No, he doesn't.**

If your only premise to the question is the fact that Batman sounds a bit similar to Liam Neeson in that scene (which I won't even deny), then I have to say this doesn't seem to be enough for suggesting such a quite unlikely possibility. Even in light of a yet missing denial by the film-makers, **there just doesn't seem to be any reason at all why Liam Neeson would dub this scene** (or any Batman dialogue for that matter).

Now why does he still sound a bit that way? You have to consider that Batman's voice is largely distorted in the first place. And especially in that scene he is standing quite far away, so **he has to shout *and* there's quite a bit of echo from the alley**. All this contributed to his voice not sounding like his normal Bat-voice but a bit more low and clean, or "Neesonesque" for that matter.

<sup>(On top of that, it also sounds to me as if this was filmed and recorded on location and not overdubbed later, which would definitely speak for Chsritian Bale talking himself, but I might be wrong with that.)</sup>